# Can an ios host app implement more than one keyboard extension?

Tags: ios, ios-keyboard-extension

I have a request to implement a keyboard extension for an established ios app that already appears to have a keyboard extension. I've been reading docs, but I am having trouble discerning if a host app can have more than one implementation of a keyboard extension point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating a demo app with two keyboard extensions I can confirm this works - at least in within a dev environment. I have no reason to believe this wouldn't pass app store submission.